# how can I get control of my wpf application started through shell registry editor only with the keyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, shell, regedit, winlogon

I have modified the following value of the registry editor:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon “Shell” = "MyApp.exe"` .

To start my application ***WPF*** instead of ***explorer.exe*** that is only operated by the keyboard, however when my application is started I can not control it with the keyboard forcing click on my application or pressing **atl + tab** to control it. Is there any code or method to have control directly?